# Create list from multiple lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I saved the results of a loop in a varibale. Now I have multiple (>500) separate lists. Which was okay for the beginning, but now I would like to work again with those lists. Do someone has an idea how I can create one list out of those multiple lists?

The code I have so far:

```
for f in file:
 #do some stuff
  my_results =[]
  if score >= 0:
   my_result.append(str(score))
  print my_result
```

So the results in my_result look like:

```
['3']
['8']
['6']
 ...
```

But I want them to be like:

```
[['3'], ['8'], ['6'],...]
```

I tried it this way:

```
one_list = []
for item in my_result:
    one_list.append(item)
```

But unfortunately it didn't work!
So is there a way how I can combine all those lists to simply one list?

Thanks fo your help! :)

Comment: Can you post a short example of the data?  You would be better off creating your list the way you need instead of *re-working* it later.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `my_result` at every iteration, as you've put the initialization part inside the loop. Put it outside the loop, so that it become initialized only once.

```
my_results =[]
for f in file:
    #do some stuff
    if score >= 0:
        my_results.append(str(score))
print my_result
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! I did it exactly the way you suggested and my_results is now like:

Comment: This will give a `NameError`, as you are appending to the undefined name `my_result`. You initialized `my_result*s*`.

Comment: I still didin't get result I'm looking for. The reason I wanted one bg lists is to get the number of all lists created. So would it be possile to count how many results I get through the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you seem confused about for loops. This should do what you want:

```
my_result = []
for f in file:
    #do some stuff here
    if score >= 0:
        my_result.append(str(score))
print my_result
```

The problem with your current code is that you keep setting `my_result` to an empty list `[]` for every item in file, thereby deleting all previous entries.

By the way, there is a typo throughout your code snippet as well as the other answer; `my_result` and `my_results` are two different lists so your code will not work because you want to assign to one list but actually assign to a completely different one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension, that would be fast, if you are not doing some stuff inside the for loop.

```
my_result = [str(score) for score in file if score >= 0]
```